# Problem with Partial Form in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i tried to make a partial form.but an error like this occured:

```
SyntaxError in Vorlesungs#new

Showing /home/babak/Management/app/views/vorlesungs/_Form.erb where line #1 raised:

compile error
/home/babak/Management/app/views/vorlesungs/_Form.erb:1: dynamic constant assignment
..._assigns[:submit_lable];Form = local_assigns[:Form];;@output...
                              ^
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <html>
2: <body>
3: <p>
4: <table>
```

that is my _Form code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<table>
  <tr align="center" style="width: 100%">
    <td width="25%"></td>
    <td width="50%">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name : </td>
          <td><%= v.text_field :Name %> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name de Professur :</td>
          <td><%= v.text_field :Leiter_name %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Proffesuren :</td>
          <td><%= v.text_field :Professuren %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= submit_tag submit_lable%></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my view:

```
<%= form_for(@vorlesung) do |v| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'Form',:locals => {:v =>v,:submit_lable =>'Update'} %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your partial name lowercase.